# Pandas df['col1':'col2'] giving the output I don't understand

Tags: python, pandas

I was doing something very basic like this -

```
data = np.arange(1,13).reshape(4,3)
table = pd.DataFrame(data, index = list('abcd'), columns =['foo','bar','baz'])
table

  foo bar baz
a  1   2   3
b  4   5   6
c  7   8   9
d 10  11  12
```

And then I ran this -

```
table['bar':'foo']
#output

  foo bar baz
c  7   8   9
d 10  11  12
```

I don't get why I am getting this result. Note that I am not asking for any other solution or workaround. I am just looking for explanation/rules behind this behavior.

Comment: Looks like you can't use slicing for column names, the slicing only works on the rows, so only `c` and `d` are (lexicography) between `bar` and `foo`

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirly sure, but it looks like you can't use slicing for column names, the slicing only works on the rows, so only `c` and `d` are (lexicography) between `bar` and `foo`

You can instead use `loc`:

```
table.loc[:, 'foo':'bar']
```

Note that I changed the order of `foo` and `bar`, this is because they are ordered as you defined them, `foo` -> `baz` -> `bar` and not lexicographically. `'bar':'foo'` will return an empty dataframe.

Answer (score 2):

It's basically outputting row slices by comparing `bar` and `foo` lexicographically with the existing column names. The output includes column `c` and `d` as they're only two columns that fall between `bar` and `foo`: `a < b < bar < c < d  < ... < foo`

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to know that the notation `df[x:y]` try to slice your dataframe by index labels and not columns. This is different than the notation `df[x]` which try to select a column. A generic way to filter your dataframe is to use `.loc` (or `.iloc`). You should the documentation about [Indexing and selecting data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html)

```
>>> table['bar':'foo']
   foo  bar  baz
c    7    8    9  # 'bar' >= 'c'   (a b bar c d    )
d   10   11   12  # 'd' <= 'foo'   (a b     c d foo)
```

When you use your code you raise an exception because we often use a `RangeIndex` or `IntIndex` index label:

```
>>> table.reset_index(drop=True)['bar':'foo']
...
TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on RangeIndex with these indexers [bar] of type str
```

Immediately, we understand the problem and use `.loc`:

```
>>> table.loc[:, 'foo':'bar']
   foo  bar
a    1    2
b    4    5
c    7    8
d   10   11
```